# Updating choice = (choice % 6) + 1 from python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, typeerror

I have a program that requires *choice = (choice % 6) + 1*, which I wrote in python 2. When I try to run it in python 3, I get *TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting*. I have just updated to python 3, and fixed most things in this program, however I can't seem to fix this so python 3 will accept it. I am relatively new to Python, and I can't find the easy answer to this in the python 3 changelog. All help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: In Python 3 `input()` returns a string, so you will need an extra `int()` call around `input()`.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you have something like `choice = input("Enter your choice")` in your program. You have to know that in Python 2, whatever you entered in `input` was directly evaluated as Python code. So if you enter a "5", you get the number 5.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> choice = input()
42
>>> type(choice)
<type 'int'>
```

This poses some risks, so its use is generally discouraged, and you should use `raw_input` instead. In Python 3, `input` was changed to return the original string (like `raw_input` in Python 2).

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> choice = input()
42
>>> type(choice)
<class 'str'>
```

To turn it into a number, just do `choice = int(choice)`.